# grep: one pattern works but not the other

Tags: grep, design-patterns

I have a teb-delimited file that has gene names in one column and expression values for these genes in the other. I want to delete certain genes from this file using grep. So, this:

```
"42261" "SNHG7" "20.2678"
"42262" "SNHG8" "25.3981"
"42263" "SNHG9" "0.488534"
"42264" "SNIP1" "7.35454"
"42265" "SNN"   "2.05365"
"42266" "snoMBII-202"   "0"
"42267" "snoMBII-202"   "0"
"42268" "snoMe28S-Am2634"   "0"
"42269" "snoMe28S-Am2634"   "0"
"42270" "snoR26"    "0"
"42271" "SNORA1"    "0"
"42272" "SNORA1"    "0"
```

becomes this:

```
"42261" "SNHG7" "20.2678"
"42262" "SNHG8" "25.3981"
"42263" "SNHG9" "0.488534"
"42264" "SNIP1" "7.35454"
"42265" "SNN"   "2.05365"
```

I've used the following command that i've put together with my limited terminal knowledge:

```
grep -iv sno* <input.text> | grep -iv rp* | grep -iv U6* | grep -iv 7SK* > <output.txt>
```

So with this command, my output file lacks genes that start with sno, u6 and 7sk but somehow grep has deleted all the genes that has "r" in them instead of the ones that start with "rp". I'm very confused about this. Any ideas why sno* works but rp* not?

Thanks!

Comment: could you paste some input example and your expected output here?

Comment: done! should've thought about it.

Comment: is that true, you only need the lines with 3rd column==0?

Comment: oh no, it was just a coincidence that the lines that start with sno there had a value of 0 on the third column. I want to filter based on the second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grep` command uses regular expressions, not globbing patterns.

The pattern `rp*` means "'r' followed by zero or more 'p'".  What you *really* want is `rp.*`, or even better, `"rp.*` (or even just `"rp`, there's no point in trying to grep for anything after the "rp" after all). Likewise, `sno*` means "'sn' followed by zero or more 'o'". Again, you'd want `sno.*` or `"sno.*` (or even just `"sno`).

Comment: thanks KAK, seems like * was the culprit. I need to learn more about regex.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question, there is one thing in your sample command line that you may want to be careful with: Whenever you use a special shell metacharacter (like "`*`"), you need to escape or quote it. So your command line should look more like:

```
grep -iv 'sno*' <input.text> | grep -iv 'rp*' | grep -iv 'U6*' | grep -iv '7SK*' > <output.txt>
```

Often, shells are smart, and if no files match the glob, they will use the text as-is (so if you enter "foo*" but there are no filenames starting with "foo", then the string "foo*" will be passed to the command).

Comment: Thanks Adam, I will definitely keep that in mind, however even when I use quotes I loose genes that start with an r (or any other gene that has an r in it)

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep -iEv "sno|rp|U6|7SK" yourInput
```

**test:**

```
kent$  cat b
"42261" "SNHG7" "20.2678"
"42262" "SNHG8" "25.3981"
"42263" "SNHG9" "0.488534"
"42264" "SNIP1" "7.35454"
"42265" "SNN"   "2.05365"
"42266" "snoMBII-202"   "0"
"42267" "snoMBII-202"   "0"
"42268" "snoMe28S-Am2634"   "0"
"42269" "snoMe28S-Am2634"   "0"
"42270" "snoR26"    "0"
"42271" "SNORA1"    "0"
"42272" "SNORA1"    "0"

kent$  grep -iEv "sno|rp|U6|7SK" b
"42261" "SNHG7" "20.2678"
"42262" "SNHG8" "25.3981"
"42263" "SNHG9" "0.488534"
"42264" "SNIP1" "7.35454"
"42265" "SNN"   "2.05365"
```